# Iphone Loading another UIView to the active Window

Tags: iphone, uiview, window

if i have got 1 Window and in the interface builder i add a second view, then in the Main Interface Builder Window I see 2 Views which are both called "View". How do I add one of this views programmatically to the m and the h file, and what do i have to edit in the interface builder so that i can run the second generated view (how do i name it,..)

Is there a possibility to send a value to the other view, and to send one back (return)? Where can I read about it.

Thx in advance,

Andreas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode, you need to create a view controller subclass or a view sublass, and create IBOutlets and wire them to Interface Builder's views, and set the type of the view or VC to the subclass you created.  There is much to explain.  You really should look at [this](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007514-CH1-SW1).